# MySQL error after attempting to convert Microsoft SQL function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a function I made in Microsoft SQL into a function for MySQL however I have absolutely no clue how to do that. I tried converting the original code through SQLines and messing with it to no avail.

The working Microsoft code is

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TotalTripsGuideFunc] (@guideid CHAR(4))
 RETURNS VARCHAR
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @trip_counts INT
    DECLARE @results VARCHAR
    SELECT @trip_counts = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Reservation,dbo.TripGuides WHERE Reservation.TripID = TripGuides.TripID AND TripGuides.GuideNum = @guideid
    SELECT @results = @guideid + ' has ' + CAST (@trip_counts AS VARCHAR(4))+ ' guides '
 RETURN @results
 END
```

and the attempted MySql code is

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION TotalTripsGuideFunc (p_guideid CHAR(4))
 RETURNS VARCHAR(1)
 BEGIN
    DECLARE v_trip_counts INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_results VARCHAR(1);
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_trip_counts FROM Reservation,TripGuides 
    WHERE Reservation.TripID = TripGuides.TripID AND TripGuides.GuideNum = p_guideid;
    SELECT v_results = concat(p_guideid , ' has ', CAST(v_trip_counts AS CHAR), ' guides ');
    RETURN v_results;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Which returns the error

> ## 1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function

EDIT

Here is the revised code

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION TotalTripsGuideFunc (p_guideid CHAR(4))
 RETURNS VARCHAR
 BEGIN
    DECLARE v_trip_counts INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_results VARCHAR(30);
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_trip_counts FROM Reservation,TripGuides 
    WHERE Reservation.TripID = TripGuides.TripID AND TripGuides.GuideNum = p_guideid;
    SET v_results = concat(p_guideid , ' has ', v_trip_counts, ' guides ');
    RETURN v_results;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Which returns the new error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN DECLARE v_trip_counts INT DEFAULT 0; DECLARE v_results VARCHAR(3' at line 3

Comment: return like this `RETURN ( v_results )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistakes:

`DECLARE v_results VARCHAR(1);` should be a little bigger like `DECLARE v_results VARCHAR(30);`

`RETURNS VARCHAR(1)` should be `RETURNS VARCHAR`

You used the `select into` right in the first select and wrong in the second. Just need to fix it:

```
-- from
SELECT v_results = concat(p_guideid , ' has ', CAST(v_trip_counts AS CHAR), ' guides ');
-- to
SELECT concat(p_guideid , ' has ', v_trip_counts, ' guides ') INTO v_results;
-- OR just:
SET v_results = concat(p_guideid , ' has ', v_trip_counts, ' guides ');
-- no need for CAST, MySQL will do implicit conversion
```

EDIT: here is a working final version:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION TotalTripsGuideFunc (p_guideid VARCHAR(30)) RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_trip_counts INTEGER;
    DECLARE v_results VARCHAR(30);
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_trip_counts FROM Reservation,TripGuides 
    WHERE Reservation.TripID = TripGuides.TripID AND TripGuides.GuideNum = p_guideid;
    SET v_results = concat(p_guideid , ' has ', v_trip_counts, ' guides ') ;
    RETURN v_results;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still receiving this error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
    DECLARE v_trip_counts INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_results VARCHAR(1' at line 3`

Comment: Can you edit your question adding the changed version please ?

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: Try this version I just posted please.

Comment: @user3183938 Hi, did it work for you? If so, please consider in accepting the answer. You do so by clicking on the V icon on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return like this `RETURN ( v_results )`

Comment: Not needed. Please read the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html